# Deal with babel config and plugins

Tags: webpack, jestjs, babeljs, babel-jest

I am building react SSR (with express) app and decide to cover some code with tests. I started with just plain js (ES6 and no jsx), not a big deal. But after running *npm test* I see output like this sometimes

```
@babel/preset-env: `DEBUG` option

Using targets:
{}

Using modules transform: auto

Using plugins:
  proposal-numeric-separator {}
  proposal-logical-assignment-operators {}
    <another plugins (dozens of them)>
  transform-modules-commonjs {}
  proposal-dynamic-import {}

Using polyfills with `usage` option:

[/<path>/file.js] Added following core-js polyfills:
  es.number.constructor {}
  es.number.is-integer {}
  es.number.to-fixed {}
```

No matter were tests passed or not. It just appears and annoys me a lot. How can I deal with these messages?

In my *webpack.config.js*

```
const js = {
  test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  use: {
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    options: {
      presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'],
      plugins: ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties']
    }
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: ['src', 'node_modules'],
    extensions: ['.jsx', '.js'],
    unsafeCache: true,
    alias: {}
  }
};
```

*.babelrc*

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "debug": true,
        "useBuiltIns": "usage",
        "corejs": 3
      }
    ],
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"]
}
```

Comment: `"@babel/preset-react"` it imight not be needed if you use just js

Comment: @bluehipy I'm using not just js. The file that I am trying to mock is js

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I fixed it by commenting *"debug": true* line in *.babelrc*. I don't think I need a wall of text in a console every time I change test cases